Threshold Classifier
I have a simple classifier that classifies incoming values based on a threshold value.
The threshold value is 0.005.
The classification is as follows:

thresh == 0.005:
if value <= thresh: class == 1,
if value > thresh: class == -1.

Now I would like to assign numbers between 0 and 1 so that they represent a probability. A value of 0.0025 or less is already very certain and should be mapped to 1. A value of 0.005 should be mapped to 0.5. A value of 0.0075 or greater is very certain and should be mapped to -1.
What could such a function look like?
